# Why is the CSS selector :parent not working?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list that is empty at first, and gets populated dynamically with JavaScript. Now I want the list to have a border only when not empty, but `:empty` and `parent` selectors do not match.

In the `html.erb` file, the list is declared as this:

```
<ul id="cepage_list" />
```

It's populated (adding `li`s) upon user input in a form above, that's working fine.
Now I have this in the CSS:

```css
ul#cepage_list
{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left:0px;
  background-color: white;     
}
ul#cepage_list:parent
{
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
ul#cepage_list:empty
{
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Default style applies correctly, but the ones with pseudo-class selectors apply weirdly. Here's the behavior:

- on page load, red border applies, that's ok
- on adding `li`'s, nothing (would expect the `:parent` selector applies)
- on clearing the list ( `.empty()` with jQuery), OK.

But why is the `:parent` pseudo-class not recognized when there are child `li`s under the list?

(tested on Chrome and Firefox 14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<ul>` is not a self-closing tag. Change it to:

```
<ul id="cepage_list"></ul>
```

Also, `:parent` isn't a real pseudo-class. Did you mean `:not(:empty)`?

Comment: thx, that solves the first question ok, but not the issue with the `:parent` selector.

Comment: How did I become persuaded that there was a :parent selector in CSS? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `:parent` selector as to which you refer to it as.

Here's a link for [more about parent selectors](http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).